# BaseColumns interface of a ContentProvider, what to put in it?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

When looking at examples of `ContentProviders` most of them included a `BaseColumns` interface. When comparing the different implementations, each one has varied amounts of methods inside. What are the best things to put inside of a `BaseColumns` interface and what should you not put in?

Example of a `BaseColumns` interface:

```
 public static interface LentItems extends BaseColumns {

   public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = LentItemsProvider.CONTENT_URI;

   public static final String NAME = "name";

   public static final String CATEGORY = "category";

   public static final String BORROWER = "borrower";

   public static final String CONTENT_PATH = "items";

   public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE + "/vnd.cpsample.lentitems";

   public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE + "/vnd.cpsample.lentitems";

   public static final String[] PROJECTION_ALL = {_ID, NAME, CATEGORY, BORROWER};

   public static final String SORT_ORDER_DEFAULT = NAME + " ASC";
 }
```

another example

```
 public class Note {

  public Note() {
  }

  public static final class Notes implements BaseColumns {
    private Notes() {
    }

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://"
            + NotesContentProvider.AUTHORITY + "/notes");

    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.jwei512.notes";

    public static final String NOTE_ID = "_id";

    public static final String TITLE = "title";

    public static final String TEXT = "text";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BaseColumns` is an interface that just provides two fields `_ID` and `COUNT`. It's generally implemented because the `_ID`(`_id`) field at least is required by different widgets(like `ListView`) to be present in the `Cursor` used by their adapters.

You can implement/extend that interface to have that field adding whatever you want besides that(keeping it relevant to the class).

> what are the best things to put inside of a BaseColumns interface?

You don't put anything in the `BaseColumns`, you extend/implement it to use its fields. Whatever you see there besides that comes from the developers that wrote the `LentItems` interface or the `Note` class.